# If there is a list holding 300,000 objects all the time, will gc have a bad performance?

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection

There is a list which is holding 300,000 objects all the time, which won't be cleaned by gc.

If the jvm configuration "Xmx" have a big enough value, will this big list make gc have a bad performance?

I'm asking this because I want to use a big list and data cache in my application. If a big list doesn't affect GC, it's the best choice to do this, because a list in jvm has better performance than others, e.g. memcached, memory db,

Comment: "a list in jvm has better performance than others, e.g. memcached, memory db" -- Now I'm curious: What List implementation? What benchmark pointed that?

Comment: @PaoloVictor, for example, a ArrayList for simple **add** and **get** with locks. I think it has better performance because serialization is not needed.

Comment: So are you just speculating or have you done any tests to validate your hypothesis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, probably not. The GC will see that those objects are long-lived, and move them to an area of the heap that is designed to hold long-lived objects.

Comment: Will GC check the references of objects in list each time? Will this operation cost much time? And can I use a big list as cache in program?

Comment: Your application will probably be fine, modern GC are pretty advanced. However, for the complete answer you will have to test your application to see whether it meets your performance objectives.

Comment: On the default GC, long-lived objects are checked on higher time intervals. Also, why do you want to use a list (and not e.g. a heap) as a cache?

Comment: @PaoloVictor, what do you mean to use a **heap** as a cache? Isn't a list in heap?

Comment: I meant the heap data structure: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure), but it depends on the removal policy you want to use. If you go for LRU, I'd recommend using a map for storage and a heap for deciding what entries to remove.

Answer (score 2):

First, why to use a list as a cache? I guess you'll need a lot of accesses to this cache? If this is the case, maybe you need to think about a Map implementation.

About the GC performance, if your cached objects will stay referenced for a long time, they'll be automatically moved to the old generation (a place in the heap, containing long lived objects), and in this generation, the GC will not be called often, so it's better in terms of performance.

If you want to learn more about GC with JDK6, here is a good link :
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html